# array list stream find index and update a value

Tags: java

How can I update an item the arraylist using stream, example I want to update item 1 from 100 to 1000:

```
    List<PayList> payList = new ArrayList<>();
    payList.add(new PayList(1, 100));
    payList.add(new PayList(2, 200));
```

I am able to find the index, but how can I find the index and then update the value?

```
   int indexOf = IntStream.range(0, payList.size())
                            .filter(p -> trx.getTransactionId() == 
   payList.get(p).getTransactionId())
                            .findFirst().orElse(-1);
```

Comment: Is PayList mutable? Does it have a method like `setAmount` to update 100 to 1000?

Comment: @roby it's not mutable, yes it has setAmount method.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options:

Using the index you have already obtained, you can use `paylist.get(index)` again. However you must handle the missing `-1` case:

```java
int indexOf = IntStream.range(0, payList.size())
                       .filter(p -> trx.getTransactionId() ==
                                    payList.get(p).getTransactionId())
                       .findFirst().orElse(-1);
if(indexOf == -1) {
    // handle missing
}else {
    payList.get(indexOf).setAmount(1000);
}
```

If you don't need to handle the missing case you could stream over the lists like this:

```
final Stream<PayList> filtered = payList.stream().filter(p -> trx.getTransactionId() == p.getTransactionId());
final Optional<PayList> first = filtered.findFirst();
first.ifPresent(i -> i.setAmount(1000));
```

Or you could use similar `orElse`, `ifPresentOrElse`, `orElseThrow` type logic on the optional to handle the missing case.